# How to resolve this flask sqlalchemy error "sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError"?

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

```python
from datetime import datetime
from pack import db,login_manager
from flask_login import UserMixin

# SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS = False

@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    return User.query.get(int(user_id))

class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(20), unique = True, nullable = False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(150), unique = True, nullable = False)
    password = db.Column(db.String(60), nullable = False)
    profile_pic = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable = False, default = "default_profile_pic.jpg")
    posts = db.relationship('Post', backref = 'author', lazy = True)
    comments = db.relationship('Comment', backref = 'commentor', lazy = True)


    def __repr__(self):
        return f"User('{self.username}','{self.email}','{self.profile_pic}')"
    
class Post(db.Model,UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable = False)
    date_posted = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable = False, default = datetime.utcnow)
    content = db.Column(db.Text, nullable = False)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable = False)
    post_comments = db.relationship('Comment', backref = 'commentor', lazy = 'dynamic')

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Post('{self.title}','{self.content}','{self.date_posted}','{self.comments}')"

class Comment(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    comment = db.Column(db.String(100000), nullable = False)
    timestamp = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable = False, default = datetime.utcnow, index = True)
    user_comment_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable = False)
    post_comment_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('post.id'))

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Post('{self.comment}','{self.user_comment_id}','{self.post_comment_id}')"
```

This give this error:

```python
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: One or more mappers failed to initialize - can't proceed with initialization of other mappers. Triggering mapper: 'mapped class Post->post'. Original exception was: Error creating backref 'commentor' on relationship 'Post.post_comments': property of that name exists on mapper 'mapped class Comment->comment'
```

Please help me resolve this error. I want to add a feature to comment on a post and for that i am trying to connect the *Comment* model with *Post* and *User* models.

Answer (score 0):

In your error you have: `Post.post_comments': property of that name exists on mapper 'mapped class Comment->comment`.

It seems that in `User` you have `comments` which creates a backref `'commentor'` in Comment and in `Post` you have `post_comments` which also creates a backref `'commentor'` in Comment.

For example in `Post`, you can change `post_comment` to :

```
post_comments = db.relationship('Comment', backref = 'post_commented', lazy = 'dynamic')
```

Edit:
When defining a One to Many relationship with backref parameter, there is no need of `user_id`  (in Post), `user_comment_id` (in `Comment`),  `post_comment_id` (in `Comment`): Simply remove them.

You should have another look at https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/basic_relationships.html#one-to-many (the backref part)

Comment: Even if i change the name still it giving error in **user_comment_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable = False)
    post_comment_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('post.id'))** both varibles are giving null values